# Updating database record from excel userform

Tags: excel, database, vba, userform

I am looking to update a database record using a userform. I have set up a userform with and ID number at the top and below are list of boxes that match the rest of the database. When the ID number is selected I would like all the other boxes in the userform to be filled e.g. using a vlookup. Below is the current formula but isn't working as all of the lookup functions are in red

```
Dim SLNo As Integer

SLNo = cmbdid.Value

Me.TextSendCode.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets(“EditForm”).Range(“B10:K13”), 2, 0)

Me.TextReceiveCode.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets(“EditForm”).Range(“B10:K13”), 3, 0)

Me.ComboEntity.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets(“EditForm”).Range(“B10:K13”), 4, 0)

Me.TextAccNumber.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets(“EditForm”).Range(“B10:K3”), 5, 0)
```

Error states - `"Expected: list separator or )"` - this is on the colon between B3:K13

Any help to make work?

Comment: If you're not working withing with charts then it's a good idea to change `Sheets` to `Worksheets` and it's almost always a good idea to qualify the `Workbook` as well.  You say "boxes", do I infer the type of box by the name property you assigned?  Is this a typo `Range(“B10:K3”)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Your double quotes are not the right ones. You are using `”` and they should be `"`. Actually, the ANSI number of whatever you are using as double quotes is 148 and you should use the ones with number 34.

Note the differente:

Yours: `(“B10:K13”)` VS the right one `("B10:K13")`

Replace your double quotes with `"` in all cases.

> [ANSI character set](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html)

Actually, this should avoid the error you are getting:

```
Dim SLNo As Integer

SLNo = cmbdid.Value

Me.TextSendCode.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("EditForm").Range("B10:K13"), 2, 0)

Me.TextReceiveCode.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("EditForm").Range("B10:K13"), 3, 0)

Me.ComboEntity.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("EditForm").Range("B10:K13"), 4, 0)

Me.TextAccNumber.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("EditForm").Range("B10:K3"), 5, 0)
```

**UPDATE:** Last line of your code is:

`Me.TextAccNumber.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("EditForm").Range("B10:K3"), 5, 0)`

Notice you have typed `Range("B10:K3")` with a `3` instead of `13` . I guess it should be `Range("B10:K13")`

Comment: Thanks now when I run I get the error: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. Any idea why?